# index one Fano manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

suppose $X$ is a Fano manifold of index one.

is there a classificatin of such Fanos, just as we have of index $dim(X)$ of $dim(X)+1$.

thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There is probably no better classification of index one Fano manifolds than for arbitrary Fano manifolds.  Here is one construction illustrating this: let $X$ be a Fano manifold of index $r$, i.e., $\omega_X^\vee \cong \mathcal{L}^{\otimes r}$ for some ample invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$.  Assume that there exists a smooth anticanonical divisor $D$.  Then the cyclic $r$-sheeted cover of $X$ branched over $D$ has index one.  So, since you can produce index one Fano manifolds starting from Fano manifolds of arbitrary index, the problem seems hopeless.

Just one more example.  For every Fano manifold $X$, consider $X\times \mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^2$.  This is again a Fano manifold, and it has index one.  Of course this ridiculous example is remedied by working with the "pseudo-index" rather than the index.